Axios request response 401 in React Native app, but working in Postman and browser?
Request failed with status code 401
this is the error that i am getting in my react native application in response to this api call
     const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/general-setting`, {
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                    }
                });
                const generalSetting = response.data.data.general_setting;
                const newTheme = {
                    baseColor: `#${generalSetting.base_color}`,
                    secondColor: `#${generalSetting.secondary_color}`,
                };
                setTheme(newTheme);
            } catch (error) {
                Alert.alert('Error Fetching Theme', 'Please check your internet connection and try again.');
            }
        };

but in  Postman or in the browser I am getting the response correctly. Here it is
Api response in postman 
I tried the same api in browser,  its working there also but not in my react native application

It looks like the 401 error indicates an authentication problem. Sometimes this problem can be from missing information in the request or it could be server-side, try:

Authentication Headers: make sure you send the authentication token correctly in the headers, if necessary. Something like:


headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
    'Accept': ‘application/json’,
}



CORS: Although Postman and the browser work, React Native sometimes has restrictions. If it's a CORS issue, check that the server allows requests from your app's origin.

As a recommendation try to check these areas and compare the headers and Authorization in Axios with Postman. Also make sure to send all the information you have in Postman (Header, Authorization, etc..).

In the header section there must be Authorization token for protected routes. In postman see the header section, there should be authorization token(assuming Bearer token). Copy it and in .env or .env.local paste it as
AUTH_TOKEN=<Copied-token>

and in headers along with it add
Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.AUTH_TOKEN}`,

Note: This is just for temporary solution. For permanent solution, On time of login the cookies is set with the token value and attached with every requests to protected route.

its not a protected route and i am not using any kind of token and cookie in browser or postman ,i have created a react web application to test that its also working in react web app but in my react native mobile application i am getting this error

The 401 status code is for "not authorized" used for authentication required routes. The authorization in postman if not visible then may be set to "Inherit from parent" in which case may be in higher folders. If it is not a protected route and still throws a 401 error, then the issue is with the backend. And judging from its functionality of fetching themes which has higher chance that it is a protected route(Makes sense because it may vary from user to user)

The is not with the authentication. My friend had build the Rest Api and there is no authentication required. I have tried fetching data in simple javascript using fetch, in React app using axios and in Nodejs, postman and browser, I am getting the response there. But in my React Native app, it shows this error. It worked 2 times before but now I am continously getting this error when I execute the app without making any changes in code.

Then the issue is with the backend. Backtrack the changes made on the backend to locate the cause of the issue. You can see the docs for status codes meaning. here

there are no changes in backed or fronted since , why should it working in other apps and postman if there is issue in authenticating the request !

I found the solution to this issue. Here's what was causing the problem and how I resolved it:
Problem: The API was returning a 401 error when accessed through a VPN on my physical device that I am using to run my React Native application, but worked fine without the VPN.
Reason: The Laravel API was blocking requests from VPN IP addresses. This is likely due to security measures implemented on the server side. Many web applications and APIs implement IP-based security rules to prevent unauthorized access and potential attacks.
